# TypeError: Cannot read property 'eth' of undefined

Tags: ethereum, web3js, ether

So I have this problem with this code and cant seem to figure out why i am getting this error when I run the script with the terminal:

> (node:30800) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'eth' of undefined

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

class TransactionChecker{
    web3;
    account;

    constuctor(projectId, account){
        this.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/' + projectId));
        this.account = account.toLowerCase();
    }

    async checkBlock(){
      let block = await this.web3.eth.getBlock('latest');
      let number = block.number;
      console.log('Searching block ' + number);

      if (block != null && block.transactions != null){
        for (let txHash of block.transactions){
          let tx = await this.web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash);
          if (this.account == tx.to.toLowerCase()) {
            console.log('Transaction found on block: ' + number);
            console.log({address: tx.from, value: this.web3.utils.fromWei(tx.value, 'ether'), timestamp})
          }
        }
      }
    }
}

let txChecker = new TransactionChecker('6bad75506d6649428e0e34ba41d51805', '0x9cad169749bBF8a3Fd735B26C21F2C7F4D8c5383');
txChecker.checkBlock();
```

Can anyone with a better understanding of this assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an misspellings in `constuctor`, thus `this.web3...` line never run. Correct one is `constructor`.

In your code there is another problem, when you use websocket, you dont need to use `HttpProvider` just pass websocket url to web3:

```
this.web3 = new Web3('wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/' + projectId);
```